# Mozc custom key mappings

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, input-language, mozc

In Anthy, it's possible to set up custom mapping for keys

For instance, you could map `#` to `ぁ`

I've done quite a bit of looking around the settings, as well some Google searching, and can't find anything. Does anyone know how to do this or if it's even possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Mozc setup, General Tab > Input mode, you have a choice of

1. Kana (direct keys for Hiragana letters)
2. Romaji (use of alphabetical phonic method)

In the keyboard setting, you can choose various Japanese keyboard layouts. Which are like US, UK and Dvorak.

Answer (score 0):

You can map your keys to japanese [from ibus-mozc](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/src/data/preedit/romanji-hiragana.tsv):

1. Click on `Gnome Status` menu (Gnome's top-left bar) > `IBus` menu (i.e. keyboard/input language selector) > Select `Japanese Mozc` input method.
2. Click again on `Gnome Status Menu` > `IBuz` > `tools` > `Properties` > `Mozc Settings` window.
3. From `Keymap` section > click on `customize` button (second one, from `Romaji table`).
4. Create new entries with your specific keys to binding the romaji-hiragana keys.
5. If messed things up, click on `reset to defaults` button from `Mozc Settings` window.

The screenshots about [image: how to edit your ibus-mozc]